# Rotation matrix for a line - my alternative approach

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

*Request vetting everything, including trigonometry part. However, the main issue is the second approach used to find the rotated points.*

This question arose in context of a question for rotation (extrinsic, i.e. of the point & not frame) in counter-clockwise direction by $30^0$  for a line $y = 5x+1$. It was easy to understand the rotation matrix given as (on [pg. #8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqrAY.png) of the text by William Ford, titled: Numerical linear algebra with applications):

$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\frac{\pi}6) & -\sin(\frac{\pi}6) \\
\sin(\frac{\pi}6) & \cos(\frac{\pi}6)
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
y_1
\end{pmatrix}$, with parametric form adopted leading to $x_1 = x, y_1=5x+1$.

The book then takes two points on the line, given as $(0,1), (1,6)$ corresponding to $x=0,1$.

But, a thought arose regarding expressing the second matrix instead as $\begin{pmatrix}
r\cos\alpha \\
r\sin\alpha
\end{pmatrix}$, with $\alpha$ being the original slope of line & $r$ as  magnitude of the vector.

But, $r$ (magnitude of vector) is changing at each real value of $x$; but $\alpha$ is constant, irrespective of $r$. 

 So, the available strategy reduces to either:
 (i) taking a common parametric form for $x_1, y_1$ as in book, & then taking two points on the line, or
 (ii) taking $x_1=r\cos\alpha, y_1= r\sin\alpha$ with computation of two points as say $(-1,-4), (1,6)$; giving slope $=\frac {10}2= 5$. Alternatively, using limits can find the limiting value as $\alpha = \arctan(5 + \frac 1x)= 5$. 
This leads to $\cos\alpha =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan^2(\alpha)+1}}=
 \frac1{\sqrt{6}}, \sin\alpha = \frac5{\sqrt{6}}$, for $0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{2}$, i.e. in the first quadrant (where $\arctan$ is taken only in the interval $(-\frac{\pi}2, \frac{\pi}2)$, but want positive value for both $\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha$).

So, taking a fixed value of $r$, i.e. for a given point $(0,1)$, $r=1$.   
 So, get the rotation matrix as : $\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
y_1
\end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\frac{\pi}6) & -\sin(\frac{\pi}6) \\
\sin(\frac{\pi}6) & \cos(\frac{\pi}6)
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac1{\sqrt{6}} \\
\frac5{\sqrt{6}}
\end{pmatrix} \implies \begin{pmatrix}
0.866 & -0.5 \\
0.5 & 0.866
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac1{\sqrt{6}} \\
\frac5{\sqrt{6}}
\end{pmatrix}$
$\implies x_1 = \frac{0.866-2.5}{\sqrt{6}}, y_1 = \frac{5*0.866+0.5}{\sqrt{6}}
$, as rotated coordinates for a given point $(0,1)$. 
But, as the rotation is for a line, so need compute two points' rotation to get the new equation of rotated line, as given below:
Taking second point, let: $(x_2,y_2)=(1,6)$, find the rotated coordinates as above by just modifying $r=\sqrt{37}$ for the new coordinates of the vector (with the same slope $\alpha$ as earlier):
$\begin{pmatrix}
0.866 & -0.5 \\
0.5 & 0.866
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt{37}}{\sqrt{6}} \\
\frac{5*\sqrt{37}}{\sqrt{6}}
\end{pmatrix}\implies x_2 = x_1*\sqrt{37}, y_2 =y_1*\sqrt{37}$

But, this gives slope of the rotated line as : $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{y_1}{x_1}= \frac{5*0.866+0.5}{0.866-2.5} = -2.95593635= -71.309^0$, or $-1.2445801$ radians.

(i) If I am correct, then need just one point's coordinates to find the slope of the rotated line, rather than two.

(ii) But, am not sure about the correctness (or the way I have shown it correct) of the rotated angle, as found below:
The angle $\alpha$ has value $=\arctan(5)=78.69^0$, or $1.3734$ radians. Adding $\frac{\pi}6$ radians or $30^0$ (positive, as counter-clockwise rotation) yields $108.69^0$. 
 
This angle lies in 2nd quadrant, so $(108.69^0-90^0)=18.69^0$. This angle taken clockwise from the $x$-axis in 2nd quadrant is $= -(90^0-18.69^0)= -71.31^0$.

Comment: Please give some sort of response, with reason (as expect down-votes).

Comment: No point on the line being rotated can be expressed in the form $r(\cos \arctan 5, \sin \arctan 5)$. On the other hand, it should be obvious that the slope of the rotated line is $\tan(\pi/6+\arctan 5)$.

Comment: @amd I hope you mean that $r$ has to be given a particular value, i.e for a given point on the line. I have stated this fact in OP, that $r$ varies with point on line. This is an imp. point, which I did not elaborate (or thought ) upon.

Comment: No, that’s not what I mean. $r(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ is a parameterization of a line through the origin with slope $\tan\alpha$, which is parallel to the one being rotated. You can certainly find the slope of the rotated line using this parallel line, but if the ultimate goal is to find the image of the original line, you need at least one point on *that* line.

Comment: @amd Thanks a lot for that. It has helped me better to visualize parameterization in this case. Also, it has explained why one point is enough to find image of the line.